# Is there a way to inquire if a class contains an instance variable with some known name?

Tags: mysql, dart, dart-mirrors

When intercepting an error from MySql, it's not known beforehand what will be the contents of the error-class passed to me. So I code:

```dart
.catchError((firstError) {
  sqlMessage = firstError.message; 
  try {        
    sqlError = firstError.osError;
  } catch (noInstanceError){
    sqlError = firstError.sqlState;
  }
});
```

In this specific case I'd like to know whether e contains instance variable `osError` or `sqlState`, as any of them contains the specific errorcode. And more in general (to improve my knowledge) would it be possible write something like `if (firstError.instanceExists(osError)) ...`, and how?

Comment: Can you just use an "is" expression to test which exception class this is? Mirrors are a heavyweight hammer, and difficult to compile to js, better just to use "is" if you can.

Comment: Can you give an example, please. an "if (class.variable is String)" throws an exception if variable is not defined in class

Comment: You can't test for the existence of a variable on an object in Dart without mirrors. However you can test to see if an object is a class, and since you know that a class will always have the variable this is all you need.  if (ex is MySqlException) { print(ex.sqlState); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

...

// info about the class declaration
reflect(firstError).type.declarations.containsKey(#osError);

// info about the current instance
var m = reflect(firstError).type.instanceMembers[#osError];
var hasOsError = m != null && m.isGetter;
```

Answer (score 1):

Günter's answer correctly shows how to use mirrors, however for your particular use case I'd recommend using an "is" check instead of mirrors. I don't know the mysql API specifically but it could look something like this:

```
.catchError((error) {
   sqlMessage = error.message;
   if (error is MySqlException) {
     sqlError = error.sqlState;
   } else if (error is OSError) {
     sqlError = error.errorCode;
   }
})
```

Perhaps ask [James Ots](https://github.com/jamesots), the author of [sqljocky](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky) for advice.